# Keep client to server connection open and close on request

Tags: java

I have a TCP client application in Java, through this application i can communicate with a server application.

I have a simple method sendCommand which sends the message to the server:

```
void sendCommand(String command) throws IOException {
    String ipaddress = "192.168.0.2";
   Socket commandSocket = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
  BufferedWriter out = null;
  BufferedReader in = null;
  BufferedWriter outToDetailFile = null;
  FileWriter fstream = null;
  String version = "";
  int numberOfBallsInGame;
  int ledCycleState = 1;


         commandSocket = new Socket(ipaddress, 7420);


      out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(commandSocket.getOutputStream()));
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandSocket.getInputStream()));


      out.write("c");out.flush();
          out.write(command);out.flush();

                String message = in.readLine(); 

                //System.out.println(message);

     out.close();
      in.close();
      commandSocket.close();

}
```

Now, because the server application is on the machine which does not accept more than 2 connections in 20 seconds i need to modify my method and "split" it in 3 different methods (i think).
My plan is the following:
I would like to call the connection to the server in one thread, keep it opened untill i want to close it, but i should be able to send the commands between opening the connection and closing it.

I'm pretty new to Java and i'll try to explain here exactly what i want to do:

1) I want to open the connection to TCP server.
2) After opening the connection i want to be able to send commands to an already opened connection by calling this method:

```
void sendCommand(String command) throws IOException {
  out.write("c");out.flush();
      out.write(command);out.flush();

  }
```

And after i'm finished with sending commands i want to call some method to close my running connection.
Because i'm pretty new to java it would be very nice if someone could show me how to achieve this or modify my method.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: But ... why do you need threads for that ? Can't you open the connection, send commands and then close the connection ?

Comment: How can I open the connection, click the button now and send a command, click the button in lets sa 2 minutes and send a command to existing connection, then click the button in any time later and send another command and after i'm finished then click a button and close the connection.